# Global gemset not visible after installing Ruby with RVM

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, gemset

I installed RVM the usual way:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

During installation these messages were displayed:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #configure
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #download
(...)
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #extract
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #validate
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #setup
'ruby' was not found, cannot install rubygems unless ruby is present (Do you have an RVM ruby installed & selected?)
Saving wrappers to '/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/bin'.
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #importing default gemsets (/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/gemsets/)
Creating alias default for ruby-1.9.3-p286.
Recording alias default for ruby-1.9.3-p286.
Creating default links/files
Saving wrappers to '/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/bin'.
```

The "'ruby' was not found" message is suspicious....

And, when I call `gem list`, the list is empty.

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
```

But then I call `rvm use ruby@global` then `gem list`, I get:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.2.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
```

So, apparently, my "global" gemset is not visible from the "default" gemset. Can you tell me why?

Here is the output of `rvm info` for "global" gemset:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p286@global:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux rmaruszewski 3.2.0-32-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:33:09 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "ubuntu/12.04/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.16.17 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "12 minutes 37 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p286"
    date:         "2012-10-12"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2012-10-12 revision 37165"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global"
    ruby:         "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin:/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin:/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/bin:/home/rmaruszewski/bin:/home/rmaruszewski/bin/build:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt:/opt/AccurevTools/bin:/opt/accurev/bin:/home/rmaruszewski/bin/gitscripts:/srv/git/development/tools/gts/bin:/srv/git/build/Build:/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/bin:/opt/grails/bin:/opt/gradle/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286"
    IRBRC:        "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "global"
```

And this is for the "default" gemset:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p286:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux rmaruszewski 3.2.0-32-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:33:09 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "ubuntu/12.04/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.16.17 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "18 minutes 26 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p286"
    date:         "2012-10-12"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2012-10-12 revision 37165"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286"
    ruby:         "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin:/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin:/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin:/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/bin:/home/rmaruszewski/bin:/home/rmaruszewski/bin/build:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt:/opt/AccurevTools/bin:/opt/accurev/bin:/home/rmaruszewski/bin/gitscripts:/srv/git/development/tools/gts/bin:/srv/git/build/Build:/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/bin:/opt/grails/bin:/opt/gradle/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286:/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286"
    IRBRC:        "/home/rmaruszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: If you downvote, at least show some guts and leave a comment why.

Answer (score 2):

I think I ran into the same exact problem except on Mac OSX 10.7.

I'm new to ruby.  I am going through the netuts tutorial (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/singing-with-sinatra-the-recall-app-2/).

I installed RVM, upgraded to the latest Ruby (mac comes with 1.8.7), setup rvm to default to 1.9.3, gem installed sinatra, datamapper, etc. but when I try to require "datamapper" in either the IRB or a .rb file, I get the "LoadError: cannot load such file -- datamapper" error.

I gem installed data_mapper instead and that seems to work, but, this seems to be some type of configuration issue that I don't understand.

I'm posting because I see the same versions as you for RVM (1.16.17) and ruby (1.9.3-p286) and I have the same RVM version in my gem list --local (rvm 1.11.3.5).

Not sure how I can have RVM 1.16.17 and the gem says rvm 1.11.3.5.  Also, rubygems is supposed to be 'included'in 1.9 but in the irb if I type require "rubygems" it returns false.

I hate being a n00b...sorry I don't have an answer.

Comment: Well, @rmaruszewski I'm crawling away from ruby n00b.  In my case, and for a reason I don't fully understand yet, the solution is to `require "data_mapper"`.  but thanks for posting this because it was as stepping stone to getting to the bottom of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

did you used the ruby in first place:

```
rvm use ruby
```

Comment: Sure. Before I had another version of Ruby installed, then I uninstalled it, and then installed RVM. It's possible that something (a configuration file, perhaps) has left from the previous installation and now interferes with RVM.

Comment: As a temporary workaround I've switched to the global gemset by default.